# Do unbiased regression coefficents yield better prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, unbiased-estimator, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

I ask myself if a have a omitted variables bias in my regression modell the coefficients of the model are biased so the mse growth because this coefficents are biased right? So does it mean if i include the omitted variable and reduce the bias of the coefficents I also reduce the mse of the model and get a better out of sample prediction?

Answer (score 3):

No, that does not hold, because of the bias-variance tradeoff.

Yes, adding more predictors that actually do have an effect will reduce the bias of your parameter estimates. But it will also increase the variance of all parameter estimates, and this increase in variance will carry through to increase your prediction error. Whether the variance-induced increase of MSE outweighs the bias-induced reduction depends on the specific situation.

[My answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/514235/1352) to [Why strong seasonality in time series of total shipped volumes not observed in customer groups?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/514223/1352) points to a simple simulation exercise I once did that illustrates this effect. Simpler incorrect models can yield lower MSE predictions than more complex correct ones.

Comment: Another example is that when Ridge regression is tuned for prediction, the optimal lambda is rarely 0, but that means the estimated betas are no longer unbiased.